# ION template banner positioning

Tags: css, header, height, nav, banner

Using https://templated.co/ion

I’m having trouble re-positioning the banner a little lower to allow for use of a logo image at top left instead of  text. When I load the page with the new header height, it briefly flashes the correct height white background, but the banner doesn't move down and the page reverts to original positioning, leaving the logo overhanging the banner image, even though I replaced some inherits and increased height of nav.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, this is what you're looking for (adjust to your needs - `5em` is demonstrative):

```css
#header {
  height: 5em;
  line-height: 5em;
}
#skel-layers-wrapper {
  padding-top: 5em;
}
```

Please note this has to be loaded after `style.css` (or placed at the very end of it, if you place your own mods inside this file). Alternatively (but not recommended), you could just modify the existing values on lines `880` and `884`.

Typically, the best way to go when making customizations is to just place them in a separate file and load it after the original resource, which should remain untouched.
This provides your project with better code control, increased maintain-ability & upgrade-ability. Placing the custom file after the original one allows you to apply changes without having to increase the specificity of the original selectors.

Comment: I had already tried separate style sheet and loading in after, also within html after style.css in the <head>. Thank you for your response. It reminded me to try one other thing. The only way I could get it to work was to add the new height and line-height to the header tag inline.. Not ideal, so will take another look.

Comment: Use a browser Dev Tool to inspect the currently applying styles. From what you describe, your custom `CSS` did not apply (possibly due to an error/typo). Use an online validation to check your `CSS` if you're not already using an IDE that does it automatically. If you need more help, provide a verifiable (inspect-able) example.